# Meteor facebook login - user is not show in SignIn space

Tags: facebook, meteor, facebook-login

I try to add Facebook login function on my app, it work but I have some problems

I start with:

```
meteor add accounts-password 
meteor add accounts-ui 
meteor add service-configuration
meteor add accounts-facebook
```

Then I write a test app on facebook, adding login and get my appId and secret
[image: developers facebook app]

I copy documentation's code to configure settings (server side) and I put my appId and secret

```
ServiceConfiguration.configurations.upsert(
    { service: "facebook" },
    {
        service : "facebook",
        appId: '123456789012345678',
        secret: '123456789012345678123456789012345678123456789012345678',
        loginStyle : "popup",
        requestPermissions: ['email','user_friends']
    }
);
```

I try to login with facebook and I have (showing in console.log) all the data I need (the picture is the picture profile in facebook), but the SignIn name is nto show in the top of the app
[image: Login with facebook]

When I signin with a normal email password login I have no problem
[image: Login with email/password]

Comment: To mark a question as solved, please click the tick icon adjacent to a helpful answer, so it turns green. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in this function:

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user) {
    var imgAvatar = "/img/user.png";
    var username = "NewPlayer_" + Math.floor(Math.random() * (9000 - 1000) + 1000);

if (user.hasOwnProperty('services') && user.services.hasOwnProperty('facebook')  ) {
    imgAvatar = "http://graph.facebook.com/" + user.services.facebook.id + "/picture/?type=small";
    username = user.services.facebook.name;
}
return user;
});
```

I discover the correct way to use this function in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30050159/accounts-oncreateuser-adding-extra-attributes-while-creating-new-users-good-pra)

```
 Accounts.onCreateUser((function(_this) {
     return function(options, user) {
          options = {
              username: 'pippo'
          }
          return Object.assign({}, user, options);
    };
 })(this));
```